# Split string with spaces to vector of strings in C

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have a `char* str` which points to a string say "22 3 43 5". I need to store this into a vector(1-d array) say `char *vec[]`, such that,
`vec[0]="22"` and so on
How can it be done?

Comment: use `sscanf`. it stops reading when it encounters spaces.

Comment: The language C doesn't have vectors. That would be C++. If you mean array, then write array. If you mean an array whose size is not known at compile time, write dynamic array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as shown below:

```
char str[20] = "22 3 43 5";
char *vec[4];
int i=0;
char *p = strtok(str," ");

while(p!= NULL )
{
   vec[i] = malloc(20); /* Free the memory once you are done using it */
   strcpy(vec[i],p);
   p = strtok(NULL," ");
   i++;
}
```

If you have

```
char* str = "22 3 43 5";
```

Then `str` is a string literal and it is read-only and `strtok()` changes the passed string so you might see a crash.

Edits:

`strotk()` function is helpful to break the char array into tokens based on a delimiter. Here I am making use of the same and breaking the char array into tokens using space as delimiter and each token is been copied to the vector. `vec[i]`. Where `vec` is array of pointers and for each pointer I allocate memory and copy the token to it .

Comment: I do not know the number of spaces separated sub-strings in the bigger string

Comment: It will work. He is asking that he is not knowing the no of spaces like `i < 4`. Just remove that condition he may accept it.

Comment: I can declare a sufficiently large vector for my purpose. right ?

Comment: Yes you can this is just an example

Comment: I would be a great help, if you can give me some insight of the code